# How to load cedet, semantic et. al only when .cxx,.h .cpp files are open

Tags: c++, emacs, elisp, cedet

Because I use Emacs for many things these days I would like to only load cedet.el when I open a c/C++ source or header and not everytime emacs starts since it takes a significant toll on the startup time.

Right now the beginning of my init file looks like this:

```
  (load-file "~/.emacs.d/plugins/cedet/common/cedet.el")

(semantic-load-enable-excessive-code-helpers)
;;(semantic-load-enable-semantic-debugging-helpers)

(setq senator-minor-mode-name "SN")
(setq semantic-imenu-auto-rebuild-directory-indexes nil)
(global-srecode-minor-mode 1)
(global-semantic-mru-bookmark-mode 1)
```

And it keeps going. 
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my emacs startup improved dramatically after i learned to use `eval-after-load` and `autoload`.

if you have a mode you only want loaded when you open a file of the type, add something like this to your .emacs (assuming foo-mode is defined in foo-mode.el on your load path):

```
(autoload 'foo-mode "foo-mode" nil t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.foo\\'" . foo-mode))
```

if you have some helper libraries which you only want loaded after you load a "main" library, add something like this to your .emacs (assuming bar-mode is a secondary mode which enhances foo-mode):

```
(eval-after-load "foo-mode"
  '(progn
    (require 'bar-mode)
    ;; ... do other bar-mode setup here ...
    ))
```

so, in your case, you probably want to setup cedet using `eval-after-load` `c++-mode`.

Comment: I added this but it doesn't seem to work: 
'code'(
(eval-after-load "c++-mode"
'(progn
  (load-file "~/.emacs.d/plugins/cedet/common/cedet.el")
))
)
Do I have to add the autoload and add-to-list statements also ? Because if I do opening a cpp file won't yield the c++ mode active on it ( i.e. no syntax highlighting).

Comment: Scratch that I needed to put (eval-after-load "cc-mode" instead of "c++-mode. Now it works seamlessly and I don't need to check if cedet was loaded and what not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```lisp
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook (lambda ()
  (load-file "~/.emacs.d/plugins/cedet/common/cedet.el")
  ;; any code dependent on having this file loaded
))
```

If loading the file (or doing the other commands) several times is a problem, you should of course first check whether this file was already loaded (either test for something defined in cedet.el, or maintain an is-loaded flag yourself).

**Edit:** Such a flag might look like this:

```lisp
(setq need-to-load-cedet-p t)
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook (lambda ()
  (if need-to-load-cedet-p
    (progn (load-file "~/.emacs.d/plugins/cedet/common/cedet.el")
           (setq need-to-load-cedet-p nil))
    ;; code that should only be executed once after cedet is loaded goes here
  )
  ;; code that should be executed every time a new buffer is opened goes here
))
```

Comment: I think i tried adding a hook but something was screwy there and it would be still loaded automatically.  emacs lisp .el files don't count as c-mode right?

Comment: Well it's not really working since if I open a second C/C++ source it will barf saying that CEDET is already loaded and then the code that depends on cedet, say semantic , will not be loaded for that second buffer. Since semantic is a cedet package I have to place (require 'semantic-gcc) and all the other semantic stuff inside the c-hook lambda scope.

Comment: I already acknowledged the possibility of that problem and told the solution (although in text, not in code): Just check if the file was already loaded. I'll add some explicit code for that to my post (probably suboptimal: because I don't know cedet, I cannot use anything from it to check, so I'll just add a flag).

Comment: No need for an extra flag; just check for (featurep 'cedet).